# GetAwaitor error message while using await foreach

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I habe a c# class like this:

```
 class EvictionProcessor
    {
        public string DataSource {  get; set;}
        public string InitialCatalog { get; set; }
        public string Query {get; set;}
    }
```

my aim is to deserilize a json, which is in text format. To do this job I have written the following code to process each element of the json async:

```
 EvictionProcessor[]  serverProperties = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EvictionProcessor[]>(Json);
            await foreach (var server in serverProperties)
            {
              //Process my JSON
            }
```

but I am getting the error which sys:

```
Error   CS1061  'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone have Idea how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Doesn't `serverProperties` need to be an `IAsyncEnumerable<EvictionProcessor>`?

Comment: yes, but in the for each  I cannot access to properties of my class for example `server.DataSource`

Comment: I'm not really sure why you want `await foreach` as the benefit to you isn't really clear here.

Comment: I would like to process each element of my json in parallel

Comment: My understanding is that `await foreach` with `IAsyncEnumerable` allows you to iterate an asynchronous enumerable (i.e. item by item). It doesn't make the `foreach` run in parallel.

Comment: `await foreach`It sounds good for me. How can I change my code to use this?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off just doing the following:

```
EvictionProcessor[]  serverProperties = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EvictionProcessor[]>(Json);
foreach (var server in serverProperties)
{
     await MyMethodToProcessJSON(server);//Process my JSON
}
```

This way if the processing can happen asynchronously you can kick off multiple tasks and then await them like so:

```
List<Task> myTasks = new List<Task>();    
EvictionProcessor[]  serverProperties = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EvictionProcessor[]>(Json);
    foreach (var server in serverProperties)
    {
         myTasks.Add(MyMethodToProcessJSON(server));//Process my JSON
    }

Task.WaitAll(myTasks);
```